# A bug for libc++ ? future and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang, libc++

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
void consumeFuture(std::future<T>&& fut) {
  fut.get();
}

template <typename T>
void actOnT(std::atomic<T>& at) {
  ++at;
}

int main() {
  std::atomic<uint32_t> a{42};
  consumeFuture(std::async(std::launch::async, &actOnT<uint32_t>, std::ref(a)));
  std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

this code compiles just fine under Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit with `g++ 4.8.1` and `libstdc++`, it fails to compile on the same platform with `clang` and `libc++` because of the `libc++` library that apparently doesn't implement everything the right way.

Is this a bug of the clang's c++ standard library or there is something wrong with my code ?

I'm using the `1.0~svn181765-1` version of both `libc++` and `libc++abi` from the official llvm apt repository.

The output obtained with `clang++` with `libc++` :

```
In file included from future_1.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:90:
In file included from /usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__functional_base:15:
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2761:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'void'
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0, "Type must be complete.");
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2778:15: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__check_complete<void>' requested here
    : private __check_complete<_Rp>
              ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2947:15: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__check_complete<void (*)(std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> &)>' requested here
    : private __check_complete<_Fp>
              ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2958:11: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__invokable_imp<void (*)(std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> &),
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> > >' requested here
          __invokable_imp<_Fp, _Args...>::value>
          ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2977:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__invokable<void
      (*)(std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> &), std::__1::reference_wrapper<std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> > >' requested
      here
    : public __invoke_of_imp<__invokable<_Fp, _Args...>::value, _Fp, _Args...>
                             ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/future:2237:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__invoke_of<void
      (*)(std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> &), std::__1::reference_wrapper<std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> > >' requested
      here
future<typename __invoke_of<typename decay<_Fp>::type, typename decay<_Args>::type...>::type>
                ^
future_1.cpp:19:17: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'async' [with _Fp = void
      (*)(std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> &), _Args = <std::__1::reference_wrapper<std::__1::atomic<unsigned int> >>]
  consumeFuture(std::async(std::launch::async, &actOnT<uint32_t>, std::ref(a)));
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Works with a more recent version of clang/libc++.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Could you specify the version of the library, clang and platform that you are using ?

Comment: Fixed by r188413 to libc++.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by this revision of libc++:
http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=188413

Comment: I'll try to recompile the library as soon as possible to verify that, thanks.